# texstudio-4.5.1-win-qt6.exe fails

Tags: texstudio, installing

I have TeXstudio 4.4.1 (git 4.4.1)
Using Qt Version 6.4.1, compiled with Qt 6.4.1 R
running on Windows 10.

It works fine; I use it a lot.

Last week I got the 4.5.1 upgrade message so I downloaded texstudio-4.5.1-win-qt6.exe.  I clicked on it, it brought up the usual do you want to allow changes dialog, I clicked yes, nothing happened.

I tried again today.  Same story.  I tried running it in Administrator mode from the get go, still nada.

4.4.1 continues to work fine so this is not an urgent question. Still...

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: perhaps run as admin?

Comment: @SimonDispa  Did you read the whole post?  Your question pretty much suggests: not.

Please note specifically this sentence: "I tried running it in Administrator mode from the get go, still nada."

Happens all the time so it's just a pecadillo.  Still, frankly, I think it's kind of rude to answer questions without actually reading them.

Comment: Oh, yeah, "and turn off real time protection" went missing.Truly sorry.

Comment: Good idea, but didn't help.  At this point I've filled out a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same problem. Turning off "Force randomisation for images" in

> Windows Security → App & browser control → Exploit protection → Force randomisation for images (Mandatory ASLR)

fixed it for me.

Comment: Hi @Crypton!  Yes, was exactly the problem.  I appreciate your effort.  That being said, the main thing I learned from this issue was that I actually like Texmaker better than Texstudio so the whole issue became moot.